# set value out of mootools request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, mootools

I want to perform a AJAX request in a function and then return the result of the request (using mootools). The request and the response are working like I want, but the variable is still 0.

here my function:

```
function recalcPrice(baseprice, rclass, count){
    var newPrice = 0;
    var request = new Request.JSON({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'controller/xhr_request.php',
        async: false, //UPDATE: that line solves the problem
        data: {
            'performaction' : 'calcNumberPrice',
            'baseprice'     : baseprice,
            'class'         : class,
            'number'        : count
        },
        timeout : 5000,
        onComplete: function(response) {
            console.log('response=' + response);
            if(response.status == 'success'){
                console.log('price = ' + response.price);
                newPrice = response.price;
            }
        }
    });
    request.send();
    return newPrice;
}
```

console shows that the price has calculated correctly, but the variable `newPrice` is not changed...

The problem is allready known in SO but shouldn't this solution made it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5541322/1059828

Answer (score 0):

ah I just missed to set asynchronous request to false

```
async: false,
```

now it's working

Comment: bad idea. solve via callbacks/events not by breaking the async nature of js.

Comment: Will be possible, but actually I don't want the user to do any action until the price is not updated. Would be not a good idea e.g. to checkout when just the number of items and not the price is updated.